# How do I generate an inverse diamond from one number?

Tags: javascript, math

So a friend of mine had an interesting homework assignment.  Her task was to create a diamond based on user input.  Sample diamond based on input of (**5**) is:

```
************
*****  *****
****    ****
***      ***
**        **
*----------*
**        **
***      ***
****    ****
*****  *****
************
```

Not too hard to do using nested loops, or recursion, however you like.

As a challenge to myself I set out to solve it with some extra criteria:

- Only allowed to use 1 loop
- Not allowed to use any variables other than the input and your loop index

I've gotten 2/3 of the way, but I know that I'm just probing blindly and I'd like to actually understand the solution.

It is somewhat similar to this [Diamond Pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983161/code-golf-diamond-pattern), but their code uses all the constructs I'm trying to avoid.

The most relevant information I've found so far is on quadratic equations, but either I don't have enough data to make viable use of them or I'm just not nerdy enough to figure it out.

Here's where I've gotten so far:

```
******
*****
****
***
**
*
**
***
****
*****
******
```

With this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
for(x=1;x<=(lines*2+2)*lines*2+(lines*2+2);x++) {
    if( ((x-1)%(lines*2+2)) <= Math.floor(((Math.abs(( (x-1)/(lines*2+2))%(lines*2+2) -lines)-0.51)+1)) ) {
        document.write("*");
    }
    if((x%(lines*2+2))==0) { document.write("\n"); }
}
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**Edit:**

I missed a major part of the assignment.  Another of the requirements is that you only print out a single character at a time.

There **has** to be some sort of mathematical relationship between row number and column number that is exploitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary variables added for the sake of clarity, you can propagate their values and remove them if you wish.

```
const N = 5;
const Nc = N * 2;
const Nr = N * 2 - 1;

for (var i=0; i<Nr*Nc; i++) {
  var r = Math.floor( i / Nc );
  var c = i % Nc;
  if ( c == 0 ) document.write("\n");
  if ( r >= N ) r = Nr - r - 1;
  if ( c >= N ) c = Nc - c - 1;
  if ( r + c < N ) document.write("*");
  else if ( r == N-1 ) document.write("-");
  else document.write(" ");
}
```

Comment: That is definitely closer to what I'm looking for.  I ended up with a lot more complexity trying to do it in 2 if statements without cascading.  This is very elegant.  I'm still curious though if there is any theory behind this since it's basically defining two inverse curves.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to tune it a little bit, but this does the job fairly well using `Array.join`

http://jsfiddle.net/8H27C/

Comment: Again, I like the use of negative indexes _for(n+1;n<-n-2;n--)_ but I don't believe using array.join is the correct answer as it's the same as looping over the array itself.

jsfiddle is extremely useful though!  I've been using [PiratePad](http://piratepad.net/) this whole time...

Answer (score 2):

This approach doesn't declare any variables, and gives the correct output:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Diamond</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre><script>
    var input = 5;
    for(var i = -input; i <= input; i++){
        document.write((new Array(Math.abs(i) + 2).join("*")) + 
          (new Array((input - Math.abs(i)) * 2 + 1).join(i ? ' ' : '-')) + 
          (new Array(Math.abs(i) + 2).join("*")) + "\n");
    }

</script></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
************
*****  *****
****    ****
***      ***
**        **
*----------*
**        **
***      ***
****    ****
*****  *****
************
```

Comment: That is an interesting solution.  I think starting with a negative index might help in with knowing left from right.  Using array.join is the same as writing _for(x in Array)_ though, so I don't believe that meets the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do your challenge is to make your loop be a single loop over all of the characters.  Now inside of your loop you first figure out the line, then where you are on the line, and then what character to print.

Comment: Based on the sample input of **5**, I can determine all of that.  With a 1 based loop, and 132 iterations...

Current row # is given by:

    _(x-1)/(lines*2+2))%(lines*2+2)_

Current column # is given by:

    _(x-1)%(lines*2+2)_